# MVC RegularExpression test user input for all spaces

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an MVC (.net core 2) view backed by a model where one of the fields is decorated as 'Required'.  This is shown below.

```
[Display(Name = "First name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]

public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

However I am finding users are tapping the spacebar in the textbox in the view to bypass validation.

The solution I was looking at was to have the field decorated with Regular Expression however I was struggling to test for if the field contains all spaces (1 or more) to throw an error to the user.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Something like `[RegularExpression(@"\s*\S.*", ErrorMessage = "Cannot be blank!")]`

Comment: Thank you - that worked perfectly.

Comment: You could also write a modelbinder that automatically trims and whitespace from your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
[RegularExpression(@"\s*\S.*", ErrorMessage = "Cannot be blank!")]
```

The `RegularExpressionAttribute` pattern must match the entire input string. So, the following pattern matches 0+ whitespaces, then any non-whitespace char, and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars, up to the end of the line.

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\S` - any non-whitespace char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, up to the end of the line.